# Azure data factory dataflow not present null values in JSON format

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, dataflow

I am looking for how to present my null values with the Azure Data Factory Dataflow activity. 
Currently, I am using standard dataflow for modelling my data from Azure SQL database and drag it into Blob storage in JSON format. 
[But if the dataset source has a null value, the column in the row is skipped in JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdKMo.png).

UPDATE:
[Here is the results of having data, having entry string as data and null value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8iPQ.png).

Please, give me some advice on how to proceed, in order to resolve the problem. With Copy activity I don't have the same issue - null values are presented with ""

Thanks in advice!
Cheers,
Vesela

Answer (score 2):

I now have a solution, you could reference it.

I recreate a table with the schema like bellow, column `setNum` has null value:

[image]

In the Data flow, I added a DerivedColumn to help us convert the null value to ''.

[image]

**Expression:**
    `iifNull(setNum,'')`: if the setNum is null, then replace it with ''.

[image]

Now, run the pipeline, 
[image]

Check the data in blob:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, I've tried, following the same steps above, but still able to see the problem. Could you please provide more information about:
1. Datasets
2. ADF version you use
3. Time zone you use.
Thank you in advice,
Cheers

Comment: @VeselaKosturkova I shared the dataset.  I import the schema and mapping manually. I rerun the pipeline(all the steps I have posted) and everything ok. I just don't if you have missed something.

Comment: Hey @LeonYue, 
Thanks again for your time, but I saw the problem - in your database setNum column is an empty string, instead of NULL value. :)

Comment: @LeonYue, NULL is different from empty strings which you seem to have, your result is not relevant to the NULL problem.

Comment: @VeselaKosturkova Sorry, I edited my answer. I have a solution that  you can add DerivedColumn expression to convert the null setNum  value to "" . This work well. Just don't know if it's the solution you want.

Comment: @VeselaKosturkova did this help you now?